I am getting this error ERROR Failed to handle answer: [Error: Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable]
Sometimes the video call is working but sometimes it isn't, and giving me this error
ERROR  Failed to handle answer: [Error: Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable]
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';
import {
  MediaStream,
  RTCPeerConnection,
  RTCView,
  mediaDevices,
  RTCSessionDescription,
  RTCIceCandidate,
} from 'react-native-webrtc';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const VideoCallScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {
  const {room, token, phoneNumber, userId} = route.params;
  const [localStream, setLocalStream] = useState(null);
  const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = useState(null);
  const socketRef = useRef();
  const peerConnectionRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    socketRef.current = io('https://mn9s5067-3000.inc1.devtunnels.ms/');
    socketRef.current.emit('join-room', {room, phoneNumber});

    socketRef.current.on('user-joined', ({phoneNumber}) => {
      console.log(`User ${phoneNumber} joined the room`);
    });

    socketRef.current.on('start-call', startVideoCall);
    socketRef.current.on('offer', handleOfferReceived);
    socketRef.current.on('answer', handleAnswerReceived);
    socketRef.current.on('ice-candidate', handleIceCandidateReceived);
    socketRef.current.on('call-ended', handleCallEnded);

    return () => {
      cleanup();
    };
  }, []);

  const startVideoCall = async () => {
    try {
      const stream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true,
      });
      setLocalStream(stream);

      peerConnectionRef.current = createPeerConnection();

      stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
        peerConnectionRef.current.addTrack(track, stream);
      });

      const offer = await peerConnectionRef.current.createOffer();
      await peerConnectionRef.current.setLocalDescription(offer);

      socketRef.current.emit('offer', {
        offer,
        room,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to start video call:', error);
    }
  };

  const createPeerConnection = () => {
    const pc = new RTCPeerConnection();

    pc.ontrack = event => {
      setRemoteStream(event.streams[0]);
    };

    pc.onicecandidate = event => {
      if (event.candidate) {
        socketRef.current.emit('ice-candidate', {
          candidate: event.candidate,
          room,
        });
      }
    };

    return pc;
  };

  const handleOfferReceived = async ({offer}) => {
    try {
      if (!peerConnectionRef.current) {
        peerConnectionRef.current = createPeerConnection();
      }

      await peerConnectionRef.current.setRemoteDescription(
        new RTCSessionDescription(offer),
      );

      const answer = await peerConnectionRef.current.createAnswer();
      await peerConnectionRef.current.setLocalDescription(answer);

      socketRef.current.emit('answer', {
        answer,
        room,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to handle offer:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleAnswerReceived = async ({answer}) => {
    try {
      await peerConnectionRef.current.setRemoteDescription(
        new RTCSessionDescription(answer),
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to handle answer:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleIceCandidateReceived = async ({candidate}) => {
    try {
      await peerConnectionRef.current.addIceCandidate(
        new RTCIceCandidate(candidate),
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to handle ICE candidate:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleEndCall = () => {
    socketRef.current.emit('end-call', {room});
    navigation.navigate('Chats', {token, userId, phoneNumber});
    cleanup();
  };

  const handleCallEnded = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Chats', {token, userId, phoneNumber});
    cleanup();
  };

  const cleanup = () => {
    if (peerConnectionRef.current) {
      peerConnectionRef.current.close();
      peerConnectionRef.current = null;
    }
    if (localStream) {
      localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
      setLocalStream(null);
    }
    setRemoteStream(null);
    if (socketRef.current) {
      socketRef.current.disconnect();
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {localStream && (
        <RTCView
          streamURL={localStream.toURL()}
          style={styles.localVideo}
          objectFit="cover"
          mirror
        />
      )}
      {remoteStream && (
        <RTCView
          streamURL={remoteStream.toURL()}
          style={styles.remoteVideo}
          objectFit="cover"
        />
      )}
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.endCallButton} onPress={handleEndCall}>
        <Text style={styles.endCallButtonText}>End Call</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#000',
  },
  localVideo: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    width: 100,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 10,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  remoteVideo: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  endCallButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 40,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  endCallButtonText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});

export default VideoCallScreen;


/** @format */

const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const userRoute = require('./routes/userRoute');
const contactRoute = require('./routes/contactRoute');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const db = require('./server/models/index');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server, {
  pingInterval: 10000,
  pingTimeout: 5000,
  reconnection: true,
  reconnectionAttempts: Infinity,
  reconnectionDelay: 1000,
  reconnectionDelayMax: 5000,
});

dotenv.config({path: './config.env'});

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development') {
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
}
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use('/api/v1/users', userRoute);
app.use('/api/v1/contacts', contactRoute);

const users = {};

io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('New client connected:', socket.id);

  socket.on('register', ({userId, phoneNumber}) => {
    users[phoneNumber] = {socketId: socket.id, userId};
    console.log(
      `User registered: ${userId} with phone number ${phoneNumber} and socket ID: ${socket.id}`,
    );
    console.log('Current users:', users);
  });

  socket.on('call-user', ({from, to, room}) => {
    console.log(`Call request from ${from} to ${to} in room ${room}`);
    const recipientUser = users[to];
    if (recipientUser) {
      io.to(recipientUser.socketId).emit('call-request', {from, room});
    } else {
      console.log(`User with phone number ${to} not found`);
    }
  });

  socket.on('call-accepted', ({room}) => {
    console.log(`Call accepted in room ${room}`);
    io.to(room).emit('request-accepted', {room});
  });

  socket.on('join-room', ({room, phoneNumber}) => {
    socket.join(room);
    io.to(room).emit('user-joined', {phoneNumber});
    console.log(`Socket ${socket.id} joined room ${room}`);

    // Check if both users have joined the room
    const clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(room);
    if (clients && clients.size === 2) {
      io.to(room).emit('start-call');
    }
  });

  socket.on('offer', ({offer, room}) => {
    console.log(`Offer received for room ${room}`);
    socket.to(room).emit('offer', {offer});
  });

  socket.on('answer', ({answer, room}) => {
    console.log(`Answer received for room ${room}`);
    socket.to(room).emit('answer', {answer});
  });

  socket.on('ice-candidate', ({candidate, room}) => {
    console.log(`ICE candidate received for room ${room}`);
    socket.to(room).emit('ice-candidate', {candidate});
  });

  socket.on('end-call', ({room}) => {
    console.log(`Call ended in room ${room}`);
    io.to(room).emit('call-ended');
    io.socketsLeave(room);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    for (const phoneNumber in users) {
      if (users[phoneNumber].socketId === socket.id) {
        delete users[phoneNumber];
        break;
      }
    }
    console.log('Client disconnected:', socket.id);
    console.log('Current users:', users);
  });
});

db.sequelize
  .sync()
  .then(() => {
    server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
      console.log(`Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT || 3000}`);
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });


Unfortunately I don't know how to solve this and i know a very little about webrtc and socket.io, I would be very thankful if you yhelp me resolve this and this is all the code, it works completely fine when i run it for the first time but when i try to call again it does not work and even after refreshing it does not work

You can refer to the examples provided on the following web page for more details:
https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#examples-and-call-flows
